# openjdk-1.7.0_55 on ubuntu: Could not load the property file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml'

Tags: classpath, java-7, java

On openjdk-1.7.0_55 on ubuntu I am getting exception:

com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Could not load the property file 'output_xml.properties' for output method 'xml'

Can this be classpath issue?

I can find "output_xml.properties" in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could be access problem, mostly i used to face the same kind of problem in fedora. So just check what is the access level ?

Comment: I am running as xxx_user and this file has read permission for all. That shoudl be enough isn't? ls -altr /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2511421 Apr 16 05:32 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME and PATH pointing to the correct jdk? Check the installation typing javac on the terminal

Comment: What are you doing when you get this error? What jars are in your classpath?

Answer (score 3):

The issue might have been caused by a recent Java update and incomplete services restart per [this page](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/38331).

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the xalan JARs in the ../jre/lib/endorsed folder

from http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/faq.html#jdk14:

> Place the xalan.jar, serializer.jar, xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar
>   in the \lib\endorsed directory, where  is where
>   the runtime software is installed.

Comment: for me, it was sufficient adding only `xalan.jar` as it pulls in the needed dependencies:

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Try ensuring that your system is consistently using the same Java version - sometimes these get out of sync.

First do `echo $JAVA_HOME` and verify that it points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/`.

Now run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and select the correct number for `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Now do the same for javac: `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SYS V init scripts and running in a container such a Tomcat, DON'T start the script directly with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
```

That will start it without a clean environment.

Instead, use the service command:

```
sudo /sbin/service tomcat7 start
```